# Unable to sort the Celltable column

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-celltable

I am trying to sort my CellTable and I am following the advice mentioned in the following example and the SO answer which are here.

http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable
[CellTable: dynamically reordering rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257216/celltable-dynamically-reordering-rows/19262375?noredirect=1#comment32171779_19262375)

but none of the solution is working. Here is my code please select me how can I enable the sorting on the table.

```
private void setComparator(ColumnSortEvent.ListHandler<MyModel> myHandler) {
    table.getColumn(0).setSortable(true);
    myHandler.setComparator(table.getColumn(0), new Comparator<MyModel>() {
        @Override public int compare(MyModel o1, MyModel o2) {
            return o1.getOrderId().compareTo(o2.getOrderId());
        }
    });

    table.getColumn(1).setSortable(true);
    myHandler.setComparator(table.getColumn(1), new Comparator<MyModel>() {
        @Override public int compare(MyModel o1, MyModel o2) {
            return o1.getOrderDate().compareTo(o2.getOrderDate());
        }
    });

    table.getColumn(2).setSortable(true);
    myHandler.setComparator(table.getColumn(2), new Comparator<MyModel>() {
        @Override public int compare(MyModel o1, MyModel o2) {
            return o1.getLastUpdated().compareTo(o2.getLastUpdated());
        }
    });

    table.getColumn(3).setSortable(true);
    myHandler.setComparator(table.getColumn(3), new Comparator<MyModel>() {
        @Override public int compare(MyModel o1, MyModel o2) {
            return o1.getQuantity().compareTo(o2.getQuantity());
        }
    });

    table.getColumn(4).setSortable(true);
    myHandler.setComparator(table.getColumn(4), new Comparator<MyModel>() {
        @Override public int compare(MyModel o1, MyModel o2) {
            return o1.getStatus().compareTo(o2.getStatus());
        }
    });

}


    public void setTableData(MyDate tableData) {
        dataProvider.setData(tableData);
    }

    public void addTableToPage() {
        if (initialize == false) {
            dataProvider.addDataDisplay(table);
            initialize = true;
        }
        addTableElements();
    }

    private void addTableElements() {
        addSortHandler();
        theView.addTable(table);
        theView.setPagerVisible(true);
    }


    public void addSortHandler() {
        ColumnSortEvent.ListHandler<SearchNewNumberOrderModel> myHandler = 
            new ColumnSortEvent.ListHandler<SearchNewNumberOrderModel>(
                dataProvider.getOrders());
        setComparator(myHandler);
        table.addColumnSortHandler(myHandler);
    }
```

Code for setting the data:

```
        public void setData(MyModelFilter dataForTable) {
            List<MyModel1> modelList = dataForTable.getList();
            setOrderList(modelList);
            updateRowCount();
    }


    private void setOrderList(List<MyModel11> list) {
            if (!UtilityService.isEmpty(list)) {
                    for (myModel1 element : list) {
                            MyModel model = new MyModel();
                            model.setfield1(element.getfieldA());
                            model.setfield2(element.getfieldB());
.... and so on
                            orders.add(model);
                    }
            }

    }
```

Comment: Of what type is your `dataProvider`? Can you show the code where you create it?

Comment: its is a asyncDataProvider

Comment: @DavidLevesque - I have added the class of dataprovider please have a look, let me know any further information is needed.

Comment: I have always used the ListHandler with a ListDataProvider, I'm not sure if it can work with an AsyncDataProvider. Can you show the code for method `dataProvider.setData()`?

Comment: I have added the code for setting the data, I am now testing with listdata provider.